# What's the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "Conjunctive Query"?

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

Assuming I have two tables : `users` and `products`.

users

```
uid | name
-------------
1   | Peter
2   | Mary
3   | Ben
```

products

```
pid | product | uid
-------------------------
1   | apple   | 2
2   | lemon   | 2
3   | banana  | 2
4   | orange  | 3
```

What is the difference between:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name FROM products p INNER JOIN users u ON p.uid = u.uid
```

and

```
SELECT p.*, u.name FROM products p, users u WHERE p.uid = u.uid
```

Are they "logically" the same? (which both gives the intersection of the two tables)

Also, is there any performance difference between them?

Comment: If you run `EXPLAIN` with both of those, you can see what MySQL does behind the scenes and then you can determine whether they're the same or not.

Comment: @Mjh Just used `EXPLAIN` command, so they seems are the same...

Comment: @Pramod Is "conjunctive query" the same as "FULL JOIN" ?

Comment: @Pramod That question is not a suitable duplicate as this has nothing to do with `full [outer] join`. This is about implicit vs explicit join syntax.

Comment: @jpw Thanks you very much!